# how to convert below string using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

i have a string

```
[{"id":"en-Us","name":"English"},{"id":"fr-FR","name":"French"}]
```

i want to convert it into

```
[{id:"en-Us",name:"English"},{id:"fr-FR",name:"French"}]
```

using javascript or jquery.
Is there any way to convert it this format, for prepoluated autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert a valid `JSON string` to a `JSON object`.

Try,

```
var xStr = '[{"id":"en-Us","name":"English"},{"id":"fr-FR","name":"French"}]'

var xObj = JSON.parse(xStr);
```

Comment: The quotes should probably changed.